# I want to make a TextView height "match_parent" whose parent height is "wrap_content" in XML (Android Studio)

Tags: android-layout

Inside the layout for my activity i have two TextView inside a RelativeLayout.

The one with id "descriptionfromDB" takes the text from a database while the other one will only show the text **Description**.
What I want is that the second one matches the height of the parent when the text of the one that gets modified become longer.

I tried to do it with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for the first TextView (since parent height grows when the other TextView's text become longer) but with no results.

[Here's an example of how it looks at the moment:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpUNn.png)

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_fontcolor"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descriptionfromDB"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/description"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_fontcolor"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the behavior you want using horizontal LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionfromDB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Using weight would be a better idea since there are many different screen sizes. Below attributes determine that the first TextView should take 30% of the parent width and second one 70% which is the remaining width.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionfromDB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you are going to add more views and nest this LinearLayout into another ViewGroup, since your layout will no longer be flat and also horizontal LinearLayout has [double layout taxation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies#double), I recommend ConstraintLayout. Same behavior using ConstraintLayout :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Description"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionfromDB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```